# Add a fullstop (period) to the end of each comment line

Tags: php, regex, eclipse

I'm trying to get around some stylecheck issues and would like to add a fullstop '.' to the end of every line which has a single line comment ( contains "//" ).

I would have thought there is a way to do this using regular expressions.

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: IDK what your asking here....

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If by "stylecheck" you mean "syntax highlighting" then you're chasing windmills. A) It's unnecessary and B) it would be quicker to download and install a better IDE.

Comment: Stylechecker meaning something that looks through the code and checks the style of the code. 

So for example, if I have a line such as this in my code:
"// this is a comment"

Then I would like to use a regular expression to search for all of these and replace with
"// this is a comment."

Comment: You *probably* would have *upvotes* if your question made sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

```
$result = preg_replace('%//.*%', '\0.', $subject);
```

The elegant way (only add a dot at the end if there isn't one already:

```
$result = preg_replace('%//.*(?<!\.)$%m', '\0.', $subject);
```

**Explanation:**

```
//      # Match //
.*      # Match any characters except newlines
(?<!\.) # Assert that the last character isn't a dot
$       # right before the end of the line
```